# Algorithm to search area on planet

Tags: algorithm, geo

I've got spahes defined somwhere on earth. I've got geographic coordinates of each of them.
I need to find these of them which are in specified distance repeatedly. I've got exact distance calculation algorithm but it is time consuming. That way I want to filter these which aren't close enough and I stack with it.

I was trying to use [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) algorithm but it do not work with geographic coordinates. 
Should I translate them to geographic coordinates - won't I lose precision of calculations and idea of may problem?
Maybe there is any other algorithm for that case (i.e. packing shapes into circles with specified center point and radius).

Thank you in advance for any word of comment.

Comment: You can map geographic coordinates to a system that nearly preserves distances. The [sinusodial projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_projection) seems to be a good choice. You could also map them to 3d positions on a unit sphere and then find the neighbours according to euclidean distance.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I was trying to use R-Tree algorithm but it do not work with geographic coordinates. Should I translate them to geographic coordinates"? You are using geographic twice there, which seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: I was trying to say that it is hard or even impossible (for me) to map geographic coodrinates (spheric nature) to rectangle which is required for 2D R-tree algorithm. Moreover, it is hard to cope with shapes defined on pole (north/south) and/or crossing [date line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line). From my point of view it is free to use any other mapping or data structure to achieve shape search functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Spatially enabled databases encapsulate all the functionality you are describing. What you need to do is to store your shapes as a geography data types in a table, create an index on that column, and then perform searches based on distance.

Most popular databases offer spatial features, including MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.